# How come del task deletes the parent directory too?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I want to delete all files under `./dist/*`  but leave the `./dist` directory itself intact (it should be empty after task runs).

```
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean:dist', function(cb){
  del([
    'dist/**'
  ], cb);
});
```

The problem is it is actually deleting the `./dist` directory too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a negation in your `glob` to prevent the directory itself from being selected:

```
gulp.task('clean:dist', function (cb) {
  del(['dist/**', '!dist'], cb);
});
```